# Read and write arrayList of Objects by using HashMap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, read-write

I want to write and read 'HashMap' to file.

My 'HashMap' is:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Descipline>> mapDis = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Descipline>>();
```

and I write to file like this:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Descipline>> entry : mapDis.entrySet()){
            properties.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        properties.store(new FileOutputStream(root + "/myMap.txt"), null);
```

But I don't know how to read it.

```
 Map<String, ArrayList<Descipline>> load = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Descipline>>();

        Properties properties1 = new Properties();

        properties1.load(new FileInputStream(root + "/myMap.txt"));

        for (String key : properties1.stringPropertyNames()){
            //something will be here to read file
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already loaded the file. Within the loop you're reading the file (i.e. the map) entries so just use again the put method

Comment: how can I read the file? I read by this way but it does not work:

'for (String key : properties1.stringPropertyNames()){
                load.put(key, properties1.get(key).toString());
            }'

Answer (score 0):

It's simple really: `java.util.Properties` is a subclass of `java.util.HashTable`, which implements `java.util.Map`, just like `java.util.HashMap` does. So you can iterate using `entrySet` like you do when saving, giving you both the key and value.

Note however that `Properties` saving and loading expects both the key and value to be `String` (a .properties file is a simplified 'ini' file), so you might want to look into `java.io.Serializable` instead.

Comment: I read file by like this and I have an java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String:

   for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Descipline>> entry : load.entrySet()){
                load.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }

Comment: More or less. As I said, `Properties` expects key and value to be `String`. Your value is `ArrayList<Descipline>`, which is not a `String`. 
Understand that both `HashMap` and `Properties` is a `Map`, so copying values between them in this way is pointless.
Can you post your `Descipline` class? Then I can give you an example of using `Serializable`.